# My question was closed in error as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, status-completed, allowed-questions

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/can-i-withdraw-my-battle-net-account-balance-into-paypal#comment102141_73601

I asked about transferring money **after**  the money was put inside the Battle.Net Account.

Other questions are asking about how, right after a sale, the money gets transferred to the user via his/her direct choice, B.Net or Paypal.

I see no other questions on this, so please reopen this thread.

Comment: ;) i like the edit reason.

Comment: also, i don't understand the reason why people vote down on posts necessarily (this isn't a youtube Thumbs Up! or Thumbs Down! system -- this post isn't unclear nor not useful.

Comment: Votes on meta don't mean the same thing as votes on the main site; here they mostly mean "I agree" or "I disagree". These votes also do not affect your reputation in any way.

Comment: Mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmk.

Comment: You can read more about meta-votes [in this meta.stackoverflow question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/the-meaning-of-down-votes-in-meta-vs-stackoverflow) :)

Comment: @RenoYeo Basically going berserk on moderators is a guaranteed way to get a lot of votes. Mostly down...

Comment: That's pretty expected actually. But I'm the rebellious kind of gamer. :P

Comment: It's okay. By the way, I'm kind of inclined to blame the other question for copy pasting a hard-to-digest wall of text. It's easy to think "wow, that wall of text _must have that answer_ somewhere in it." (I've tried to fix it.)

Comment: You know, sometimes great questions and answers just need that little bit of refining. I'm proud of such selfless people for doing the dirty work! (i'm not sucking up here, this comes from the heart -- I love to see selfless people at work.)

Answer (score 4):

> **After some discussion in chat, I've changed my mind. The original question is about battle.net, not Diablo 3.**

Your quesiton is a duplicate, because it is a subset of the other question. From the body of the Juan's question:

> What are all the ways to cash out to real life? If there are region restrictions, what are they?

This question clearly covers your question, which is:

> Can I withdraw my Battle.Net Account Balance into Paypal?

If you feel like the current answers don't answer your question you have three options:

1. Leave a comment on the accepted answer asking for more information.
2. Edit one of the posts for grammatical errors so the question is bumped to the front page in order to give it attention.
3. PLace a bounty on the question asking for more information, which also draws attention to the question by placing it in the featured tab.

Comment: I don't see how it explains if you could take the cash out of your B.Net account, though. Does this mean you can't?

Comment: @RenoYeo: The answer doesn't, but it should. THis is an example of a shortcoming in the answer, not in the question. Which is comments asking for information, as well as what bounties are intended for. You can read more about bounties [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: But its less than 2 days :/

Comment: @RenoYeo: Then leave a comment on the accepted answer asking for more information. The reason for the bounty 2-day restriction is so that a question has time to gather quality answers before someone places a bounty on it.

Comment: @RenoYeo Also, if you don't find the current answer to be acceptable, that is what downvotes are for.

Comment: But you can't put any answers if its locked, right? Aha.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Not really a fan of downvoting stuff, though. A question's a question and even if its a stupid one sometimes underneath all that gibberish its someone trying to ask something even if they don't get what they mean themselves, you know what i mean?

Comment: @RenoYeo: I'm not sure what you are referring to with [this comment](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4908/my-question-was-closed-in-error-as-a-duplicate/4911#comment14097_4911).

Comment: @RenoYeo Voting is an essential part of how this site works.  Up and down.  You can always change your vote if the answer is edited to include more info.  (I was referring to downvoting the *answer* in this case)

Comment: @Wipqozn i meant if the question was locked, users aren't able to post answers on the question itself, right? Or do you mean putting a bounty on Juan's question?

Comment: @RenoYeo I'm referring to Juan's question. As I outlined in my post, I believe that your question is a duplicate and should remain closed.

Comment: Ah, i see. Well, i'm pretty sure I have the answer now (which is no, you can't), but i hope in the future Blizzard could implement a B.Net to Paypal system... that'll be easier i guess. But quite impossible now that I think about it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it's a different question, and I voted to reopen it.

I've removed the less constructive parts from your meta post, there is no need to attack the moderators directly over this.

Comment: Its just that i've seen some valid questions over time being locked just because people think it means otherwise. It's not really a help towards the site at all, if you get what i mean. But i really apologise for any hatred directed towards mods. They have their rough days too.

Comment: It's pretty easy to get a decision reversed, just make your case in a comment, in chat or on meta. It helps significantly if you stay constructive, though.

Comment: Unlike my post just now, gotcha. :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't close your question and I agree that it is slightly different, but you should note that the answer to the question which yours was marked a duplicate of does answer your question quite clearly and that they are *very* similar.

In the second paragraph of **How do I “cash out” from the real-money auction house?**, the second sentence clearly says:

**"any proceeds from the sale of items in the real-money auction house that have been sent to the player’s Battle.net Balance will not be transferrable to the third-party payment service account."**

Comment: Right. So i guess it means no, i can't transfer anything once it's been transferred to my B.Net account, i guess.

Comment: @RenoYeo That's right. You cannot transfer once the money's been deposited or at least that's what Blizzard's FAQ currently states. Maybe in the future the may consider changing this, but this seems unlikely.

Comment: Hmm. Still, it seems weird that you can't transfer funds out of B.Net accounts. Well, its good for Blizzard though.